# Intent: Custom Action On Android

Tags: android, android-intent, action

I recently started studying Android developing. Since I have been a .NET for years it has not been very difficult to start coding and creating my first app.

I am building a test app (for study prupose) and I have a LoginActivity which has a static string field as follows:

```
 public static final String LOGIN_ACTION = "com.sid.ugho.action.LOGIN_ACTION";
```

And in in the manifest I have:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.sid.ugho.action.LOGIN_ACTION"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I call the activity as follows:

```
final Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.LOGIN_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(loginIntent, LOGIN_REQUEST_ID);
```

No big deal I guess since it all works, the activity works perfectly. My question is this: 
**when my LoginActivity is launched with that specif action how can I handle it? How can i recognize a "normal" launch (with no specif action) from a specif action launch?**

Thanks to everyone!
(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the LogInActivity, you can retrieve the action of the caller intent.

```
String filteredAction = getIntent().getAction();
```

Now if anyone launched your `LoginActivity` with `LoginActivity.LOGIN_ACTION` then you will get `com.sid.ugho.action.LOGIN_ACTION` in `filteredAction`. But if the LoginActivity was not launched with action rather with in any other way, then you would get `null` in `filteredAction`.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate` method you can take:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction()
```